# how to launch command prompt as administrator using batch file

Tags: testing, automation, nunit-2.5

I am having a NUnit used automation framework. I was working on Windows XP previously and made a batch file to execute the complete Automation test using that batch file. But now I am using Windows 7 and when i tried to run same batch file, the Nunit is not launching. but when i tried to manually launch the command prompt as administrator, my execution is working fine.

Do anyone know how to launch command prompt as administrator through batch file

Answer (score 0):

You can try following in your batch file:
runas /user:machinename\administrator cmd
OR
runas /user:domain\user cmd

Both of the above will prompt for password.

For more details you can refer to usage of "RUNAS"